# How to fix a database after sorting only a few columns when other columns were hidden

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have sorted a giant database with lots of information when several columns were hidden. One of the columns was sorted by date and when I unhid all the columns, half of all the information in the whole database is now in the wrong.

Firstly, could that be the cause of data shifting cells and secondly, is there anyway to change it back?

Comment: Have you tried undo a couple of times? Restoring from backup?

Comment: Unfortunately, it was saved yesterday and closed. We've only just noticed. There is no back up as far as I know.Alex

Comment: But you still have backups ... or not :/

Comment: Where would they be if there is one? Alex

Comment: If you're using Windows, you might have Previous Versions turned on. In Explorer, right-click on the file, go to Properties at the bottom, and look for a Previous Versions tab. If it's there, it might have old version of the file you can retrieve.

Comment: If you had one you would probably know where it was. Use this as a lesson and backup in future. Your hard disk(s) could fail at any moment ... :/

Comment: Yeah, I'm really aware of that. It's our IT team that is responsible for backups. They are installing a new server which they tell me will auto backup everything in the future. It's not in place yet.

Comment: Fix the database? What database?

Comment: "A" database. Not "the" database. Sorry.

Comment: When you say database, do you mean Excel (spreadsheet)?

Comment: Oh yes. Excel. I'm new (as if you couldn't tell) and it was in the question but it asked me to change the question.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve your current problem but I can't paste huge chunks of code into a comment. Here's some VBA that I throw into any workbook I want to be sure to backup. It makes a backup whenever it's called. I usually call it from the `Workbook_Open` event. If you don't opt for the timestamp, it backs up no more than once a day. For files I'm *really* nervous about, I call the function with a timestamp on the `Workbook_AfterSave` event, too.

```
Option Explicit

'This function saves a datestamped or timestamped copy of the file in a folders in the same location as the file
'It is typically called from the ThisWorkbook object with something like:
'Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'    BackupThisFile
'End Sub

Function BackupThisFile(Optional AddTimestamp As Boolean = False)

    Dim fPath As String
    Dim fName As String
    Dim fExt As String
    Dim iExt As Integer
    Const backupFolder As String = "Backups"

    'Get file path
    fPath = ThisWorkbook.path
    If Right(fPath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then fPath = fPath & Application.PathSeparator

    'Add the backup folder name
    fPath = fPath & backupFolder
    If Right(fPath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then fPath = fPath & Application.PathSeparator

    'Create the backup directory if it doesn't already exist
    On Error Resume Next
        MkDir fPath
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Get file name
    fName = ThisWorkbook.Name                   'Get file name with extension
    iExt = InStrRev(fName, ".")                 'Find the . separating name from extension
    fExt = Right(fName, Len(fName) - iExt + 1)  'Saves the extension
    fName = Left(fName, iExt - 1)               'Clips the extension

    'Compile path, file name, date stamp, and extension into one variable
    fPath = fPath & fName & " " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")

    'Add timestamp if required
    If AddTimestamp Then fPath = fPath & " " & Format(Now, "hhmmss")

    'Add the file extension
    fPath = fPath & fExt

    'Save a copy if it doesn't already exist
    Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not fso.fileExists(fPath) Then ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs fPath

End Function
```